# Sed / awk script for a non-standard apache access log ( Oracle Weblogic )

Tags: sed, awk

I have hit a wall with my limited sed scripting abilities, and i wonder if any of you guys could help me out.

I have a non-standard apache access log with the following format:

```
#Version:   1.0
#Fields:    c-ip date time cs-method cs-uri sc-status time-taken bytes
#Software:  WebLogic
#Start-Date:    2014-07-21  11:21:59

10.000.000.000  2014-07-21  11:22:16    GET /em/skins/login.css 200 0.1 1091
10.000.000.000  2014-07-21  13:55:36    POST    /sbconsole/sbconsole.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=Projects_ViewProjects&ProjectsPortlet=    200 0.766   519376
```

The script i have mashed together is:

```
sed -i  's/[[:space:]]\+/ /g;s/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\3-\2-\1/;s:-:/:g' log.access
```

But I have hit a wall, and would love some help so I could end with the following format in the access log :

```
10.000.000.000 - - [21/07/2014:11:22:16 +0200] "GET /em/skins/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1091
10.000.000.000 - - [21/07/2014:13:55:36 +0200] "POST /sbconsole/sbconsole.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=Projects_ViewProjects&ProjectsPortlet= HTTP/1.1" 200 519376
```

Just FYI... I have multiple different IPs that does GET/POST.

---

The following awk line got me the output that i wanted

```
awk '!/^#/ && NF{split($2,a,"-"); printf "%s - - [%s/%s/%s:%s] \"%s %s\" %s %s %s\n", $1, a[3], a[2], a[1], $3" +200", $4, $5" HTTP/1.1", $6, $7, $8}' alm_server1_51100_access.log > test.test
```

All thanks to fedorqui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice markup:

```
awk '!/^#/ && NF
     {
      split($2,a,"-")
      printf "%s - - [%s/%s/%s:%s] \"%s %s\" %s %s\n", $1, a[3], a[2], a[1], $3, $4, $5, $6, $7
     }' file
```

---

If your input is just the lines starting with `10.000`... this makes it:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s - - [%s:%s] \"%s %s\" %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}' file
10.000.000.000 - - [2014-07-21:11:22:16] "GET /em/skins/login.css" 200 0.1
10.000.000.000 - - [2014-07-21:13:55:36] "POST /sbconsole/sbconsole.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=Projects_ViewProjects&ProjectsPortlet=" 200 0.766
```

If you also want to skip the empty lines and those starting with `#`, then this makes it:

```
awk '!/^#/ && NF{printf "%s - - [%s:%s] \"%s %s\" %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}' file
```

Both approaches use the same `printf` format, that goes through the fields adding the quotes, brackets, dashes that you want.

To format the data differently, use `split()` and move the elements of the subsequent array `a[]`:

```
$ awk '!/^#/ && NF{split($2,a,"-"); printf "%s - - [%s/%s/%s:%s] \"%s %s\" %s %s\n", $1, a[3], a[2], a[1], $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}' file
10.000.000.000 - - [21/07/2014:11:22:16] "GET /em/skins/login.css" 200 0.1
10.000.000.000 - - [21/07/2014:13:55:36] "POST /sbconsole/sbconsole.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=Projects_ViewProjects&ProjectsPortlet=" 200 0.766
```

Comment: the first one works great ( after some small ugly adjustments ) I am just missing how to change the date from: 2014-07-21 to 21/07/2014

Comment: @Acehege uhms, true, didn't notice that. See update with `gsub()`.

Comment: that worked great! You are a star! just one more thing ;), how can I change the format so it is: date/month/year instead of year/month/date ?

Comment: @Acehege see update.

Comment: that worked! Thank you so much for the help. I will mark this as answered and edit my post with the line that worked for me!